How to get bash script's current line contents being processed prior to interpretation?
When using bash -x or set -x in a script the output shows the result of the line being processed but not the source line which produced the result.  There are times when knowing this as well could save time by not having to cross-reference the script with its output.
For example, if variable "x" currently has a value of 1 then source line x=$((x+1)) shows x=2 without revealing how the result was obtained - it could have been a simple x=2 assignment.  Limited testing also indicates that there is no difference between the output of a while loop and the equivalent series of if tests.
Is there any facility in bash which will return the "pre-interpreted" source line for display?

Are you looking for something more than that provided by the -v ("Print shell input lines as they are read.") option?

 No, that's exactly what I want, thank you.  After a web search turned up nothing (guess I didn't search for the right phrase) and trying more exotic things it turns out to be so simple...

steeldriver's comment about using the -v aka verbose option was what I needed to know.

Are you looking for something more than that provided by the -v ("Print shell input lines as they are read.") option?

-v (-o verbose) and -x (-o xtrace) are standard sh options, not specific to bash, the short ones from the Bourne shell in the late 70s, the long alias from the Korn shell in the 80s.
Example:
$ cat file
x=1
x=$(( x + 1 ))
printf '%03d\n' "$x"

$ bash -o xtrace ./file
+ x=1
+ x=2
+ printf '%03d\n' 2
002

$ bash -o verbose ./file
x=1
x=$(( x + 1 ))
printf '%03d\n' "$x"
002

$ bash -o verbose -o xtrace ./file
x=1
+ x=1
x=$(( x + 1 ))
+ x=2
printf '%03d\n' "$x"
+ printf '%03d\n' 2
002

Beware verbose prints the code at the time the code is read and parsed which can be long before it is run.
$ cat file
{
  x=1
  x=$(( x + 1 ))
  printf '%03d\n' "$x"
}

$ bash -o verbose -o xtrace ./file
{
  x=1
  x=$(( x + 1 ))
  printf '%03d\n' "$x"
}
+ x=1
+ x=2
+ printf '%03d\n' 2
002


$ cat file
incr_and_print() {
  local x="$1"
  x=$(( x + 1 ))
  printf '%03d\n' "$x"
}
incr_and_print 1
incr_and_print 12

$ bash -o verbose -o xtrace ./file
incr_and_print() {
  local x="$1"
  x=$(( x + 1 ))
  printf '%03d\n' "$x"
}
incr_and_print 1
+ incr_and_print 1
+ local x=1
+ x=2
+ printf '%03d\n' 2
002
incr_and_print 12
+ incr_and_print 12
+ local x=12
+ x=13
+ printf '%03d\n' 13
013


Thanks for posting the two points, I didn't know that and will make a note of it for future reference.

If switching to zsh is an option, you can print the $ZSH_DEBUG_CMD variable inside a DEBUG trap. That contains the code being run as regenerated from the internal "pre-compiled" code, so not necessarily exactly like the raw code from the file, but would likely be good enough for your use case.
$ cat file
{ trap '{ print -r "[raw:$LINENO] $ZSH_DEBUG_CMD" } >&2 2> /dev/null' DEBUG; } 2> /dev/null

incr_and_print() {
  local x="$1"
  x=$(( x + 1 ))
  printf '%03d\n' "$x"
}
incr_and_print 1
incr_and_print 12

(the redirections to /dev/null are to hide the traces for those commands whenever xtrace is enabled).
$ zsh ./file
[raw:3] incr_and_print () {
        local x="$1"
        x=$(( x + 1 ))
        printf '%03d\n' "$x"
}
[raw:8] incr_and_print 1
[raw:1] local x="$1"
[raw:2] x=$(( x + 1 ))
[raw:3] printf '%03d\n' "$x"
002
[raw:9] incr_and_print 12
[raw:1] local x="$1"
[raw:2] x=$(( x + 1 ))
[raw:3] printf '%03d\n' "$x"
013

Combined with xtrace:
$ zsh -o xtrace ./file
[raw:3] incr_and_print () {
        local x="$1"
        x=$(( x + 1 ))
        printf '%03d\n' "$x"
}
[raw:8] incr_and_print 1
+./file:8> incr_and_print 1
[raw:1] local x="$1"
+incr_and_print:1> local x=1
[raw:2] x=$(( x + 1 ))
+incr_and_print:2> x=2
[raw:3] printf '%03d\n' "$x"
+incr_and_print:3> printf '%03d\n' 2
002
[raw:9] incr_and_print 12
+./file:9> incr_and_print 12
[raw:1] local x="$1"
+incr_and_print:1> local x=12
[raw:2] x=$(( x + 1 ))
+incr_and_print:2> x=13
[raw:3] printf '%03d\n' "$x"
+incr_and_print:3> printf '%03d\n' 13
013

And with both xtrace and verbose:
$ zsh -o xtrace -o verbose ./file
{ trap '{ print -r "[raw:$LINENO] $ZSH_DEBUG_CMD" } >&2 2> /dev/null' DEBUG; } 2> /dev/null

incr_and_print() {
  local x="$1"
  x=$(( x + 1 ))
  printf '%03d\n' "$x"
}
[raw:3] incr_and_print () {
        local x="$1"
        x=$(( x + 1 ))
        printf '%03d\n' "$x"
}
incr_and_print 1
[raw:8] incr_and_print 1
+./file:8> incr_and_print 1
[raw:1] local x="$1"
+incr_and_print:1> local x=1
[raw:2] x=$(( x + 1 ))
+incr_and_print:2> x=2
[raw:3] printf '%03d\n' "$x"
+incr_and_print:3> printf '%03d\n' 2
002
incr_and_print 12
[raw:9] incr_and_print 12
+./file:9> incr_and_print 12
[raw:1] local x="$1"
+incr_and_print:1> local x=12
[raw:2] x=$(( x + 1 ))
+incr_and_print:2> x=13
[raw:3] printf '%03d\n' "$x"
+incr_and_print:3> printf '%03d\n' 13
013

As you can see verbose only prints the code when it is parsed but the DEBUG trap prints it when it is run.
